# Removing NULL elements from a list

Tags: r

```
mylist <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    123, NULL, 456)

> mylist
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
[1] 123

[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
[1] 456
```

My list has 13 elements, 11 of which are NULL. I would like to remove them, but preserve the indices of the elements that are nonempty.

```
mylist2 = mylist[-which(sapply(mylist, is.null))]
> mylist2
[[1]]
[1] 123

[[2]]
[1] 456
```

This removes the NULL elements just fine, but I don't want the nonempty elements to be reindexed, i.e, I want `mylist2` to look something like this, where the indices of the nonempty entries are preserved.

```
> mylist2
[[11]]
[1] 123

[[13]]
[1] 456
```

Comment: Someone may find a way, but I think you are falling into the "Why is it printing that way" trap. Those index numbers are not the names of your list elements. There are no names. Check `names(mylist)`. So they are just helpers showing where in the list the elements are. That's why you're having trouble telling R to return the 11th position of a list with only two elements. You can try naming the the list as the answer below.

Comment: IMO this answer should be updated to @Hayward-Oblad's purrr solution below. Either `list %>% discard(is.null)` or `list %>% discard(~ length(.x) == 0)`.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The closest you'll be able to get is to first name the list elements and then remove the NULLs.

```
names(x) <- seq_along(x)

## Using some higher-order convenience functions
Filter(Negate(is.null), x)
# $`11`
# [1] 123
# 
# $`13`
# [1] 456

# Or, using a slightly more standard R idiom
x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NULL
x
# $`11`
# [1] 123
# 
# $`13`
# [1] 456
```

Comment: or `x <- x[!sapply(x,is.null)]`

Comment: @xm1's answer is better since the right hand side expression returns the list without the `NULL`s hence can be written into a convenience function like this `remove_null_lst <- function(x)  x[!sapply(x, is.null)]`

Answer (score 73):

**Simply use `mylist[lengths(mylist) != 0]`.**

Function `lengths()` was introduced in R 3.2.0 (April 2015).

Comment: Users stuck with even older R versions can use `vapply(mylist, length, 1L)`, it's ever-so-slightly vaster (and maybe harder to read to the untrained eye)

Answer (score 63):

The **`purrr`** package, included in **Tidyverse**, has elegant and fast functions for working with lists:

```
require(tidyverse)

# this works
compact(mylist)

# or this
mylist %>% discard(is.null)

# or this
# pipe "my_list" data object into function "keep()", make lambda function inside "keep()" to return TRUE FALSE.
mylist %>% keep( ~ !is.null(.) )
```

All above options are from Purrr. Output is:

```
[[1]] 
[1] 123

[[2]] 
[1] 456
```

Note: compact() was in plyr, but dplyr superseded plyr, and compact() stayed around but moved to purrr. Anyway, all the functions are within the parent package tidyverse.

Here's a link to the Purrr cheat sheet download:

https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Or to view the Purrr cheatsheet directly in a browser:

https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_purrr.pdf

Answer (score 30):

There's a function that automatically removes all the null entries of a list, and if the list is named, it maintains the names of the non-null entries.

This function is called `compact` from the package `plyr`.

```
l <- list( NULL, NULL, foo, bar)
names(l) <- c( "one", "two", "three", "four" )

plyr::compact(l)
```

If you want to preserve the indexes of the non-null entries, you can name the list as it is done in the post before and then compact your list:

```
names(l) <- seq_along(l)
plyr::compact(l)
```

Comment: For completeness: purrr::compact() seems to do the same job.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the names you can do

```
a <- list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
          123, NULL, 456)
non_null_names <- which(!sapply(a, is.null))
a <- a[non_null_names]
names(a) <- non_null_names
a
```

You can then access the elements like so

```
a[['11']]
num <- 11
a[[as.character(num)]]
a[[as.character(11)]]
a$`11`
```

You can't get them in the neat `[[11]]`, `[[13]]` notation, though, because those represent numerical indices.

Comment: This is the closest to what you want that can actually be done though :)

Answer (score 6):

This solution works with nested list as well

```
rlist::list.clean(myNestedlist ,recursive = T)
```

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for this.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is with convenient chaining notation

```
library(magrittr)

mylist %>%
  setNames(seq_along(.)) %>%
  Filter(. %>% is.null %>% `!`, .)
```

Comment: `Filter(Negate(is.null), setNames(L,seq_along(L)))` is pretty easy to read.

Comment: Ok, fixed the issue. Negate != `!`

Answer (score 4):

here's a very simple way to do it using only base R functions:

```
names(mylist) <- 1:length(mylist)
mylist2 <- mylist[which(!sapply(mylist, is.null))]
```